# hot to prevent a mobile rewrite rule to be applied to a specific folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this rules in my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\my site\.it$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|ipad|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !mobilecookie=true
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.my site.it%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
```

I want that this rule does not apply for the folder admin and it's content.
I think this should work if placed right below the line

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/ 
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
```

But it does not.
Any help really appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Does it works if you use only the first RewriteRule and add the RewriteCond with the admin constraint ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|ipad|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !mobilecookie=true
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.my.site.it%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
```